# Swapping arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

Is there some `library fucntion` to swap the values in two dynamically allocated arrays.
Suppose i declare and initialize my arrays like:

```
int * a = new int[10];
int * b = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
a[i] = i + 1;   //stores a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
}  
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
b[i] = i + 1;   //stores b[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
}  
swap(a,b);
```

And i expect the `a` to store: **{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}**
And array `b` should store: **{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}**

Comment: You don't have arrays, you have pointers. And the difference is crucial because `std::swap` will swap the pointers (but wouldn't swap arrays).

Comment: unless you use something like `std::vector` and pass references around, swapping pointers is all you need

Comment: Also, don't forget to `delete[]` your `new[]` pointers.

Comment: I rather would say, don't use `new` if you don't need it! Like in this example. In modern C++ custom memory management should be avoided as much as possible. And if, for some reason, you still need to use it, its better to abstract it in some special class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is swapping the pointers. You can use `std::swap` for this.

```
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int * a = new int[10];
    int * b = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = i + 1;   //stores a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        b[i] = i + 1;   //stores b[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
    }

    std::swap(a, b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    std::cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << b[i] << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The dynamically allocated memory isn't touched this way, the only thing that changes are the values of the pointers `a` and `b`.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to change the value of two pointer,so the parameter is the address of pointer（int **）.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int * pA = new int[10];
     int * pB = new int[5];
     if(NULL != pA && NULL != pB)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
            a[i] = i + 1;
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
         {
             b[i] = i + 1;
         }
         swap(&pA,&pB);
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
            cout << a[i] << " ";
         }
         cout << endl;
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
         {
            cout << b[i] << " ";
         }
     }
 }

 void swap(int**pA, int **pB)
 {
     int *pTemp = *pA;
     *pA = *pB;
     *pB = pTemp;
 }
```

Comment: This is a mix of C and C++. In particular, it ignores `std::swap` and it ignores references in its `::swap` implementation.